# Embed webforms into site that is custom php

Tags: webform-civicrm

Our site is all custom php/html.  It is not built using tools like Joomla or Drupal.

Is it possible to embed webforms directly into our site?

Comment: Can you clarify where the webforms are coming from? (e.g. another site that is running Drupal?)

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM standalone profile forms can be embedded anywhere. They are just cut-n-paste html snippets.
http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/profiles/